# How to operate two modals on a page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having issues with my modal pop up. Basically, I have two pop ups. One is for the user to login with their email and password, the other modal is forgotten password where we request their email.

I had to strip the code back as I have been encountering problems. Basically modal 1 works fine as it does the following:

- Click 'Access Course' button to show modal 1
- Complete modal 1 details
- If credentials correct, logs in user
- If incorrect, modal reappears with fields empty and states if the username or access code is incorrect

So now I want to do the same for modal 2. User clicks on the 'Forgotten Password' and its modal should appear asking for an email. If the email entry is incorrect, modal reappear with field empty and message stating 'Do not recognise email'. If it's correct then it will do its process.

The problem I have is that if I enter in a wrong email and click submit, it displays modal 1 and say 'Please enter in your password' message. It should have shown modal 2 and its message.

My question is what is causing this to happen and how to fix it.

```
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

  if($_POST["submit"] == "Login"){
    ... Do modal 1 stuff
  } 
  else if ($_POST["submit"] == "Reset"){

  }
}


<body>

        <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Access Course</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <button class="buttonLink" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Forgotten Password</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
          
          <form class="modal-content animate" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
              <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            </div>
        
            <div class="container">
              <label for="username"><b>Email</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="username" required>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                <br/><br/>
              <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
              
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                
              <button type="submit" value="Login" name="Login">Enter</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="id02" class="modal">
          
          <form class="modal-content animate" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
              <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            </div>
        
            <div class="container">
                  
              <label for="reset-email"><b>Enter your email to reset your passworde</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="reset username" required>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $reset_username_err; ?></span>
                
              <button type="submit" value="Reset" name="Reset">Reset</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
        var modal2 = document.getElementById('id02');
        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }else if (event.target == modal2){
                modal2.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        
        </script>
        <?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';</script>"; 
          }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: the last echo says that it will always open modal 1 when request method is POST no matter what the content of POST['submit']

Comment: did you know you can make/build/hide/show the dom with javascript and apply events? there is no reason to have more than one modal on the dom, make it dynamic else your slowly end up up with a  modal, modal1, modal2, modal3.. and so on for every section which you show in a modal